# How can I change color of some parts of NSAttributed string created after HTML Rendering

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have an HTML string which I rendered using the following code

```
extension String {
    
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            let str =  try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
            str.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))
            return str
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
       
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

and my HTML String looks like this

```
"suix swKI mn jip ipAwr ]<br>" +
    "<span style='color:#fa8508; font-size:10px; font-weight:100;'>hy (myry) mn! (gurU dI) is`iKAw sux ky pRym nwl (prmwqmw dw nwm) jipAw kr [</span><br>"
```

it is a very small part of my string. What I want to do is when I render my html string I want the text having collars given by style to remain the same and the text other than that to change color according to light/dark mode.

I have tried using addAttribute method with foreground property, but it changes the color of whole text, how do I preserve the color given by style in this case while being able to change color of other text.
thanks

I tried using NSAtrributed string to change foreground color of some parts of my string

Comment: It's unclear which part you ant exactly to color. In `addAttribute()` there is the `range:`, option. You need to find the range to apply your color.

Comment: @Larme the problem is the style tag is present for some part of string and not for others, also it is repeated at various points in string, also I have multiple strings like this and each is of 500-600 lines, so I hoped to find a way to filter out text from html string which is not inside style tag

Comment: Could you clearly show in your sample which part you want to color, and how to find it? What's the logic behind "that part needs to be colored" and the other not?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 range of particular strings

As I have to show tagName in different color and another string in different color inside same textview

So I created 2 range and set color range wise

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: completeString)
    let range = (completeString as NSString).range(of: tagName)
    let range2 = (completeString as NSString).range(of: completeString)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: range2)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: Constants.AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .FONT_REGULAR, size: 16), range: range2)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: Constants.AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .FONT_REGULAR, size: 16), range: range)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(hexString: "#3FC1FC"), range: range)
```